# someone has been found to do job

Tags: sentence-structure

> I’m sorry, the position has been filled (=someone has been found **to do the job**).

Source: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/position

---

"**To**" is not "in order to", and "someone **to do the job** has been found" is not really natural.
What is the grammatical role of "**to**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammatical role of "to" is a subordinator. It marks the infinitive clause  "do the job".  The roles of infinitive clauses are quite general.  Often they indicate a purpose (in order to) but they have other uses. Consider "I want you to play with me". This doesn't mean "in order to".  Here it indicates what the person who has been found will do.

The infinitive clause comes after the direct object of the verb. So "find someone to do the job" is correct English.

Comment: What does "**to**" indicate? It doesn't indicate a purpose.

Comment: It is a subordinator, it marks the infinitive clause.  It doesn't indicate a purpose, infinitives have lots of other purposes. Here it indicates what the person who has been found will do.

Comment: I don't think it is a subordinator. I think it merely ties the person to the idea: do a job.

Comment: @Lambie I don't what else you'd call it.  It is the particle in the infinitive that marks the infinitive verb. Words that tie a subordinate clause into the structure of the sentence are generally called "subordinators"

Comment: But it is not a subordinate clause for me. I know there are linguists who do call it that. I have an analysis by a French linguist but it is too long to post here. No worries.

Comment: If you can read French, here's the explanation for this usage in English. https://cle.ens-lyon.fr/anglais/se-former/les-precis-et-le-workbook/precis-de-grammaire/les-suites-v1-v2-et-les-operateurs-o-to-et-ing-comment-relier-deux-verbes-qui-se-suivent-dans-un-enonce-partie-1- They call it an "operator". I'd say a function word with no meaning per se other than linking the subject to the idea that comes next.

Comment: Are you saying it is not subordinate?  Or are you saying that it is not a clause?  Are you saying that "do" isn't a verb?

Comment: Does "**to** mean "who will"?

Comment: No, it does "mean" anything.  It is just a grammatical marker.

Comment: I've read (via google translate) the link, and I think I agree with all that he says.  "To" is an "operator" (ok so I've called it a subordinator, which names the particular operation it does: subordination).  That page talks about V1 and V2, and the V2 is a clause (which is subordinate, although he doesn't use that word)  Some V1 verbs require a "to" operator/subordinator.  The exact meaning depends on context.  You can't say that "to" has a lexical meaning, it is only a grammatical operator.

Comment: May I ask one more question? I wonder if "to do the job" is a part of a noun phrase.

Comment: No,  Noun phrases are headed by nouns.  Which noun would head a noun phrase?

Comment: The noun "someone" might head a noun phrase and "to do the job" might be a part of the noun phrase.

Comment: The word "someone" is the subject of the clause. The infinitive "do the job" is pretty clearly not part of the subject.

Comment: I can't understand why "to do the job" is not part of the subject, and the reason of it is too long to write down here. I'll post a new post about it.